# Adding title and description to subpage's featured image

Tags: child-pages, images, add-submenu-page

Hej! 
I have a subpage to display it's subpage featured image. I would like to add the title and description to beneath the thumbnail. Today my code look like this >

In the functions.php

```
function my_geturls($post = NULL, $which = 'both') {
first we get the post, if no post is passed we use global post
if ( empty( $post ) ) global $post;
if ( is_numeric($post) ) $post = get_post( $post );
if ( ! $post instanceof WP_Post ) return;
$children = FALSE;
$parent = FALSE;
// if we want children posts thumbnail...
if ( $which !== 'parent' ) {
// run a query to get attachment id set as thumbnail in children posts
global $wpdb;
$q = "SELECT {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
JOIN {$wpdb->posts} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id
WHERE {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_parent = %d";
$thumb_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( $q, $post->ID ) );
// if some results, call wp_get_attachment_image_src on all ids to get image urls
if ( ! empty( $thumb_ids ) ) {
  $children = array_map( function($tid) {
     $img = wp_get_attachment_src( $tid ); // <-- SET SIZE HERE
     return $img[0];
  }, $thumb_ids );
 }
}
// if we want parent post thumbnail...
if ( $which !== 'children' && $post->post_parent ) {
$tid = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->post_parent );
if ( $img ) {
  // get the url of parent post thumbnail
  $urls = wp_get_attachment_src( $tid );  // <-- SET SIZE HERE
  $parent = $img[0];

 }
}
// if we want only children posts thumbnail return them
if ( $which === 'children' ) return $children;
// if we want only parent post thumbnail return it
if ( $which === 'parent' ) return $parent;
// if we want bot return an array with both
return array( 'children' => $children, 'parent' => $parent );
}
```

This is my code in the page.php file.

```
        <?php
    global $post;
    if ( is_page() ) {

      $thumbnails = my_get_thumbnails();

      if ( ! empty( $thumbnails['parent'] ) ) {
        $format = '<a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $child_page->ID ); ?><div class="parent-thumb"><img src="%s" class="img-responsive" id="img-center" max-height="255px" width="auto" alt="" /></div></a>';
        printf( $format, $thumbnails['parent'] );
      }

      if ( is_array( $thumbnails['children'] ) && ! empty( $thumbnails['children'] ) ) {
        $open = '<a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $child_page->ID ); ?>"><div max-height="255px" width="auto" class="child-thumb"><img class="img-responsive" id="img-center" max-height="255px" width="auto" src="';
        $close = '" alt="" /></div><a>';
        echo $open . implode( $close . $open, $thumbnails['children'] ) . $close;
      }

    }
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance!
Hannes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how it could be done!
Instead of using that function it was possible to add a query and another function.
This is the code goes in the page.php file.

```
                <?php $subs = new WP_Query( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'page', 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id' ));
    if( $subs->have_posts() ) : while( $subs->have_posts() ) : $subs->the_post();
    echo '<div class="re-featured-image child-thumb">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'index-thumb', array('class' => 'img-responsive', 'id' => 'img-center'));
    echo '<div class="re-featured-image-title">' . get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID))->post_title . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="re-featured-image-caption">' . get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID))->post_excerpt . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="re-featured-image-description">' . get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID))->post_content . '</div></div>';

    endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

If you want your thumbnail to link to it's page
add this function in the functions.php file. I found the code here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/making-post-thumbnail-link-to-post

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_image_html', 10, 3 );

function my_post_image_html( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {

$html = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id ) ) . '">' . $html . '</a>';

return $html;
```

}